# How to trigger Http Post Action to Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to Asp.net MVC and am having problems with the following code.

```
  @model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.ShippingDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SportsStore: Checkout";
}

<h2>Check out now</h2>
Please enter your details and we'll send your goods right away!
@using (Html.BeginForm("Checkout", "Cart"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <h3>Ship to</h3>
    <div>Name: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)</div>

    <h3>Address</h3>
    <div>Line 1: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Line1)</div>
    <div>Line 2: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Line2)</div>
    <div>Line 3: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Line3)</div>
    <div>City: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.City)</div>
    <div>State: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.State)</div>
    <div>Zip: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Zip)</div>
    <div>Country: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Country)</div>

    <h3>Options</h3>
    <label>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.GiftWrap)
    Gift wrap these items
    </label>


        <p align="center">
            <input class="actionButtons" type="submit" value="Complete order"/>           
        </p>


}
```

I expect the input of type submit to call the Post version Checkout action from my controller, shown below

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;
using SportsStore.WebUI.Models;

namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class CartController : Controller
    {
        private IProductsRepository repository;
        private IOrderProcessor orderProcessor;

        public CartController(IProductsRepository repo, IOrderProcessor proc)
        {
            repository = repo;
            orderProcessor = proc;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Checkout(ShippingDetails shippingDetails, Cart cart)
        {
            var test = Request.Form["Line1"];
            if (cart.Lines.Count() == 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry, your cart is empty!");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                orderProcessor.ProcessOrder(cart, shippingDetails);
                cart.Clear();
                return View("Completed");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(shippingDetails);
            }
        }

        public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

            if (product != null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(product, 1);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }

        public RedirectToRouteResult RemoveFromCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

            if (product != null)
            {
                cart.RemoveLine(product);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }

        public ViewResult Index(Cart cart, string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new CartIndexViewModel { Cart = cart, ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }


        public ViewResult Summary(Cart cart)
        {
            return View(cart);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Checkout()
        {
            return View(new ShippingDetails());
        }

        private Cart GetCart()
        {
            Cart cart = (Cart)Session["Cart"];
            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                Session["Cart"] = cart;
            }
            return cart;
        }

    }
}
```

However, whenever I press this input button, nothing happens.

Could anybody please tell me what is wrong? I thought an input button of type submit would call the post version of the action, but apparently this is not working.

Edit:

I tried disabling all javascript in the browser, but this does not solve the problem.

Here is my routing info:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)


 {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(null,"", // Only matches the empty URL (i.e. /)
            new
            {
            controller = "Product",
            action = "List",
            category = (string)null,
            page = 1
            }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null, "Page{page}", new { Controller = "Product", action = "List" });

        routes.MapRoute(null,"{category}", // Matches /Football or /AnythingWithNoSlash
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 });

        routes.MapRoute(null,
        "{category}/Page{page}", // Matches /Football/Page567
        new { controller = "Product", action = "List" }, // Defaults
        new { page = @"\d+" } // Constraints: page must be numerical
        );

        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
    }
```

And here is my ApplicationStart method in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Cart), new CartModelBinder());
    }
```

I don't really know what else to do. If anybody has any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect the input of type submit to call the Post version Checkout action from my controller

Why do you expect something like that? You don't seem to have indicated it on your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Checkout", "Cart"))
{
    ...
}
```

If you do not explicitly specify the action and controller name to be called when rendering the form, then the same action as the one that rendered this view will be called with HttpPost. So for example if this view was rendered from the `Index` action, then if you use `Html.BeginForm`, ASP.NET MVC will look for an Index action with HttpPost on the same controller.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ... render the form
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ShippingDetails shippingDetails, Cart cart)
{
    ... process the form submission
}
```

That's the convention. If you don't want to follow the convention you need to use the overload of Html.BeginForm which allows you to specify the action and controller that you want to be invoked.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I have edited the code to use Html.BeginForm("Checkout", "Cart") (and have edited the listing in my question as well). However, I am still not hitting the breakpoint and nothing happens. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So what happens when you explicitly specify the controller and action in your `Html.BeginForm`? When you submit this form it will be POSTed to the `Checkout` controller action on the `Cart` controller. Are you getting some error?

Comment: I am still not hitting the breakpoint and nothing happens. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have some javascripts running on your page that could be hijacking the form submission? Things like AJAX or something? Also you might look at the `Net` tab in FireBug to see if some request is being performed to the server when you click on the submit button. Other than that this code should work fine.

Comment: I put the breakpoint on the first line of the controller action. It never gets hit. I don't see any error. The button does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Ok when I look at the Network tab on google chrome developer tools, it shows the HttpGet version of Checkout is called when the form is first displayed. However, when I click the "Complete Order" button to submit the form, there is no traffic whatsoever. The action is not correctly linked to the button for some reason.

Comment: It seems that there is some javascript hijacking the form submission. Try disabling all javascript in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to explicitly specify that you want to POST the form. By default, it does a GET.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Checkout", "Cart", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
}
```